# Website hosted on IIS keeps asking for authentication even though only Anonymous Authentication is enabled

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2019

I recently purchased and implemented an SSL certificate for a web application that is hosted on a Windows Server 2019 machine running IIS 10. I added the certificate, created the bindings, and did all the other steps detailed in [this](https://www.godaddy.com/help/manually-install-an-ssl-certificate-on-my-iis-10-server-27349) tutorial.

The next step was making sure that the IIS Authentication was set to Anonymous Authentication (so that all users can access the site; the web app handles user authentication). The ones I checked were set to Anonymous and I thought I was done configuring the certificate.

However, when I tried to access the website, I was shown the browser authentication alert, prompting for a username and password. I tried inputting my domain credentials (admin level), the web app credentials, and the local server administrator credentials. However, none of those worked. **EDIT: When I don't enter anything, the popup goes away and I get a "You are not authorized to access this site. Please contact your administrator." message.**

What could be the problem? I called the application tech support (they were the ones who set up the server before I started) and the Senior Systems Engineer had no idea why that was happening.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/943891/the-http-status-code-in-iis-7-0-iis-7-5-and-iis-8-0 Very likely you hit 401.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I investigated the issue and it seemed to be tied to an application called **Windows Admin Center**, which I promptly uninstalled (use discretion). I then restarted the **World Wide Web Publishing Service** service. Then I found [this](https://superuser.com/a/1426716/1017245) answer on StackExchange:

> Later I uninstalled it and it's the same error. I can't find how to
> release 443 port.
>
> Per Microsoft, if you previously had Windows Admin Center installed,
> and now nothing else can use the same TCP/IP port, try running:
>
> > netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443 
> > netsh http delete urlacl url=https://+:443/

I thought that solved my issue, but I received a generic "This webpage cannot be found", even though the `http` counterpart worked as normal. To fix the issue, click on the `Default Web Site` on the left pane in IIS (first expand `Sites`), then click on `Bindings...` in the right pane, then click on the `https` entry you added and make sure your certificate is still selected when you click `Edit...`. Mine was deselected in the drop-down and the generic `Not Selected` was the value. Select your certificate again, click Ok, and it worked immediately for me.